# a macro substitution involving concatenation and line number

Tags: c++, c

I would like to have a macro that produce something like `L17`, where `17` is the line number when the macro is invoked.  However the following only produce `L__LINE__`

```
#define STOP L##__LINE__
```

Wonder if there is a way to make the `__LINE__` evaluate before concatenation.

Comment: is there any guarantee on the order of macro expansion in the standard? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37463034/719662 for fixed version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a double concat macro wrapper:

```
#define CONCAT0(x,y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT0(x,y)
#define STOP CONCAT(L,__LINE__)
int main() {
    int STOP = 42;
    L5 = 41;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!